# How to create variables from an input file

Tags: java, bufferedreader, sqldatareader

In my program I need to loop through a variety of dates. I am writing this program in java, and have a bit of experience with readers, but I do not know which reader would complete this task the best, or if another class would work better. 
The dates would be input into a text file in the format as follows:

```
1/1/2013 to 1/7/2013
1/8/2013 to 1/15/2013
```

Or something of this manner. I would need to break each range of dates into 6 local variables for the loop, then change them for the next loop. The variables would be coded for example:

```
private static String startingMonth = "1";
  private static String startingDay = "1";
  private static String startingYear = "2013";
  private static String endingMonth = "1";
  private static String endingDay = "7";
  private static String endingYear = "2013";
```

I imagine this could be done creating several delimiters to look for, but I do not know that this would be the easiest way. I have been looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file) post for help, but cant seem to find a relevant answer. What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: I suggest you look into the `SimpleDateFormat` class.  Maybe you can do something with its `parse` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options.

You could use the scanner, and set the delimiter to include the slash. If you want the values as ints and not string, just use `sc.nextInt()`

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\s*|/");
// You can skip the loop to just read a single line.
while(sc.hasNext()) {
  startingMonth = sc.next();
  startingDay = sc.next();
  startingYear = sc.next();
  // skip "to"
  sc.next()
  endingMonth = sc.next();
  endingDay = sc.next();
  endingYear = sc.next();
}
```

You can use regex, as alfasin suggest, but this case is rather simple so you can just match the first and last space.

```
String str = "1/1/2013 to 1/7/2013";
String startDate = str.substring(0,str.indexOf(" "));
String endDate = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);¨
// The rest is the same:
String[] start = startDate.split("/");
System.out.println(start[0] + "-" + start[1] + "-" + start[2]);
String[] end = endDate.split("/");
System.out.println(end[0] + "-" + end[1] + "-" + end[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String str = "1/1/2013 to 1/7/2013";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+/\\d+/\\d+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    matcher.find();
    String startDate = matcher.group();
    matcher.find();
    String endDate = matcher.group();
    String[] start = startDate.split("/");
    System.out.println(start[0] + "-" + start[1] + "-" + start[2]);
    String[] end = endDate.split("/");
    System.out.println(end[0] + "-" + end[1] + "-" + end[2]);
    ...
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1-1-2013
1-7-2013
```

Comment: Essentially, instead of creating one large string of the whole date, I could reference each part of "start" to get the month, day, year? Also, Could I just use a reader to read in each line of the text file?

Comment: @Connor In the code that I posted, `start[0]` holds "1" from `1/1/2013`, `start[1]` holds the other "1" and `start[2]` holds `2013`. So you can use a string array or string parameters to capture these values.

Comment: As for your second question, yes, you can read each line using a `Scanner` or a `BufferedReader` - and then apply the parsing part that uses the regex.